# In language variable not print '%' sign in joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am store a language string in a language variable. The problem is, that the `%` is not printed in the language string.

This is my code:

```
COM_ACCOUNT_NEW_OPEN_EMAIL_BODY = "Hello,<br> your account created for  with %s% interest.<br>Thanks."
```

Comment: try `%%` instead of single `%`

Comment: But '%s' is pass for value in language string and second one is display as '%' sign.

Comment: try second one as `%%` instead of single `%`

Answer (score 0):

Use second one as `%%` instead of single `%`

```
COM_ACCOUNT_NEW_OPEN_EMAIL_BODY = "Hello,<br> your account created for  with %s%% interest.<br>Thanks."
                                                                               ^^
```